# how to create a slanted striped design using HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, image

Is is possible to create the design shown in the image using HTML and CSS? If so then what would I need to do?

The image is zoomed in so that's why it looks pixelated. The slanted lines are overlaying on top of a different elements with different backgrounds (white and blue). The lines also blend into the background at the end.

[image]

Comment: With the blending effect?  I'm almost positive you can't do it with pure CSS (without the blending, you could just use a repeating gradient).  You *could* do it with an SVG background, which would scale without pixelating.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to use two different background images for the top and the bottom elements .  Use http://www.stripegenerator.com for the basic striped background then use your image editor of choice to create the fade.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started in the right direction. It's possible but tedious:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YB9vC/1/)

You can swap the colors easily. I couldn't get an opacity gradient for the diagonals, however.

See [here](http://ptrn.it/10tcDp5) to build the lines' CSS.